# Abrir un programa Windows desde mi aplicacion php hosteada en Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, php7

lo que deseo es desde mi aplicacion php que esta hosteada en Ubuntu Server 16 abrir un programa Windows por ejemplo Skype.exe. Es decir abro mi aplicación desde el navegador con S.O Windows con la ip ingreso a la app, en algun punto existe un botton que al dar clic abre una aplicación Windows.  Alguien sabe como hacerlo?:

Por ejemplo si tengo un boton asi:

```
<button type="button">Abrir Skype Windows</button>
```

Comment: vos queres que tu php, que se ejecuta del lado del servidor, abra un programa, en supongamos mi pc?

Comment: Si correcto eso mismo

Comment: pero tu php se ejecuta del lado del servidor.. eso lo tenes claro??? no se ejecuta en mi pc.. se ejecuta en la tuya...como sabe tu pc, que cosas tengo en mi pc?? y adonde??? (sin hablar de los problemas de seguridad si pudieras hacer algo asi)

Comment: Correcto si lo tengo claro, por eso mismo decía si se puede hacer algo al respecto o es cosa imposible ?

Comment: y... no lo veo posible.. y hasta suena raro.. si tu php esta en el servidor.. como le dice al navegador que ejecute algo en la pc donde esta, para colmo sin saber si siquiera existe? suena raro....

Comment: Con PHP no es posible y, por motivos de seguridad, el navegador tampoco te permitirá ejecutar un programa en el cliente.